# Talend jobs deployment

Tags: talend, data-integration

I am new to Talend Open Studio and I'd like to develop a job on a Macbook or a Windows PC and then export the job and run it on a Linux server as a scheduled job (i.e. cron).

The job will involve extracting data from 2 Oracle databases on different servers, getting data from a CSV file from another server and then insert the extracted data into another Oracle database server.

Can this be achieved? 
Do I need to install the same Talend release on the Linux server?

Please advise what all the software I need to install on the Linux server for it to work.

Thanks in advance
- R

Answer (score 2):

All you need on the linux box is JRE, preferably 1.7, but 1.6 could work if you build your jobs like that.

Then you build your job in talend, this will create a zip file including all the dependencies, you extract these zips on linux. they can be on the same folder so the dependencies are not stored twice.

Then schedule the .sh script in CRON.

I'd also suggest to use the built-in project level logging so you would know:

- When did the job start.
- What were the error messages.
- If you use tFlowMeter then the number of records loaded.

Comment: Balazs Gunics - thanks for your response. Will the zip file include all the libraries that are necessary for the job to execute?

Comment: Yes it will, except if you don't have those zips in your studios lib/java folder, in this case it fails to include them.